# How to structure recurring calendar events in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, calendar

I have a calendar scheme that's repetetive, lets say every monday, wednesday and friday  20:00H and every sunday 15:00H. Note that I need a 24H time format in the Dutch format.

Now I want to display only the *first three* upcoming days+dates+time in the following way:

For example when it's Monday the 10th of a month **before** 20:00H:

- show the next upcoming day + date, which is **Monday 10th, 20:00H**.
- show the date there after which is **Wednesday 12th, 20:00H**.
- and show the date there after which is **Friday 14th, 20:00H**.

After monday the 10th, 20:00H, everything moves one further:

- show the next upcoming day + date, which is **Wednesday 12th, 20:00H**.
- show the date there after which is **Friday 14th, 20:00H**.
- and show the date there after which is **Sunday 16th, 15:00H**.

I must be able to wrap some text around the given results, so it would be nice to have  three variables, for example nextdate_1, nextdate_2 and nextdate_3 that I can use within custom text.

I hope someone can help me out here.

Maurice

Comment: Are you willing to use a relational database that can be queried with SQL, or do you want to make this 100% procedural, in javascript?

Comment: How are your recurring events defined in JavaScript? Do you have a class that can calculate the next time?

Comment: @Tim: I can go all directions frome where I am now. However, the page I am using is hosted where I cannot use PHP, just javascript. So I guess a 100% javascript procedure will work best.
David: No, I don't have anything yet. So nothing is defined yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all of the event definitions loaded together as JavaScript objects

1. ask each one to calculate the next three times,
2. add them to a single array,
3. sort that array, and
4. assign the first three to your variables.

Here's a starting poing. Note that it uses jQuery's `$.each` for brevity.

```
var now = new Date(), 
    times = [],
    nextThree;
$.each(events, function (index, event) {
    var i, time = now;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        time = event.calculateNextAfter(time);
        times.push(time);
    }
});
times.sort();
nextThree = times.slice(0, 3);
```

**Update:** To model the events themselves, it depends on how complicated they need to be. A first stab would be that each event can recur on any combination of the days of the week at the same time. This seems to match what you described, assuming you have two events in your question. This can be as simple as an object containing the time as an integer and an array of booleans for the days of the week.

```
event1 = {
    time: 2000,
    days: [false, true, false, true, false, true, false]
}
event2 = {
    time: 1500,
    days: [true, false, false, false, false, false, false]
}
```

If you read up on object-oriented programming in JavaScript you can make it more complicated to add behavior. Unfortunately, we're pretty far beyond the standard SO question which is "How do I make this work?"

Comment: Hi David, this looks like a great start. Unfortunately, I'm not a great javascript coder and this looks a little like abracadabra to me. Can you please make it a little more complete for me? Thank you.

Comment: How do you plan to store these events?

Comment: What do you mean by storing the events? It's just the days+ times that I need to configure somewhere like Mon 20:00H, Wed 20:00H, Fri 20:00H and Sun 15:00H. Maybe these can be put in the script itself as a config variable? They won't change much and as they do, I think it's easy to adjust this in the variable. Is this possible?

Comment: Okay, if they don't change often then yes you can just declare them in your code as I showed in my edit.

Comment: Recurrence of calendar events can be a tricky thing. There are simple monthly and daily rules (monthly rent/mortgage payment is due! or time to wake up, sleepyhead!) but then there are other more complicated rules (e.g. in my town yard-waste can be left at the curb for pickup the 1st and 3rd Wednesdays of each month) and then there are "every-other" and every "n" rules too.  You must iterate EVERY rule to generate its next event date/time and then sort those events chronologically. An annual event might be due today, and a weekly event might not be due for another six days.